# Option to upload pictures in mobile chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

I use my mobile to access the site. The chat rooms in mobile view do not have any option to upload pictures. I have to click on Request desktop site to upload pictures everytime.

Can this feature be added like the one on desktop version? Please up vote if you support this.

Below is a screenshot of how it looks from mobile view in chat rooms.

[image]

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276085/

Comment: Yes, it's the same that I posted here.

Comment: This isn't really about physics.se, so I'm not sure why it's been posted here instead of meta.se (though it'd be closed as a dupe there)